# OCI(Oracle cloud infrastructure) user login activity audit

Tags: dashboard, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

has anyone done or knows OCI(Oracle cloud infrastructure) user login activity to audit and create a dashboard or report? I know a few built-in audits on OCI but I am looking for user audit like when logged in, current active users so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, OCI allows access through various modes like Console, CLI, SDK, Rest API, etc... So, It becomes difficult to track them. But if you are looking to track user activity on your application, you may generate application logs for login activity and configure custom dashboards with OCI Observability and Monitoring services.